# Oracle 64-bit with Classic ASP + ASP.NET 2.0

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp-classic, vb6, oracle11g

I have my project with Classic ASP and Visual Basic COM+ component. I have some pages are integrated in .NET 2.0 version. i have Oracle database as back end and everything is in 32-bit. Its hosted on Windows server 2003

Now, we are planning to Move it on Windows Server 2008. Now, My issue is on new server we are planning to install Oracle 11g in 64-bit.

and i am sure that VB COM+ components i can't recompile in 64-bit.

My question is : Can my 32 bit COM+ components communicate with 64-bit Oracle Client? I know there is Oracle 32-bit Client available but i can't use it, because on the same server i will have Congnos BI tools that will use the Oracle 64-bit client.

Can anybody have the suggest me anything?

Thanks,

Comment: it's posible to install the 32-bit version within the 64-bit installed ? or at least the 32-bit ODBC drivers???

Comment: yes, It is possible 32-bit version within the 64-bit OS. but issue is 32-bit can't communicate with 64-bit Oracle Server, for that i need 64-bit Oracle Client.